# Running VMWare API on Web Site Fails

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications, vmware, vmware-server

Im trying to write a web client which lets you manage virtual machines using VMWare API(Vix)
Im using WCF in my server technology and a website, Im also using [VMWare Tasks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31961/Automating-VMWare-Tasks-in-C-with-the-VIX-API) Wrapper that uses VMWare API

When Im trying to connect to my ESXi Server using the following(as explained in the help file) :

```
vmWareServer.ConnectToVMWareVIServer(new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/sdk",  
                                    hostServerIP)), userName, password, timeoutInSecs);
```

On regular C# project everything seems to work right...However when trying to run this line from a website application I get a TimeOut exception.

I've tried to change the SendTime/RecieveTime limits to 2 minutes in the Web.Config file, However after half second it throws this Timeout Exception...

Is any one familier with this API? Is it connected to that the Wrapper is trying to connect to Uri while its already in Web application?

I can't figure out what's going on, I've tried even in VMWare forums but no answer...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your IIS application pool under a different user ID.  For testing, try the same user ID you are using when running the winforms app.  When things work in a console/winforms app, but fail in IIS, it is usually permissions related.

Comment: Changing the Identity of the application pool from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to  "LocalSystem" solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Local system is a very priveledged user. You should create a dedicated account and only grant it the specific rights needed.